# How to stop one way WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have a One way WCf Service which will just log entries in database.Normally it will run for 10 - 20 mins . Is there any way to cancel the service when any need arises ?

On button click i'l be triggering the one way WCF service . Now m planning to add cancel button which should stop currently triggered service. Could anyone help me in achieving this.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Could you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make the operation IsOneWay, or implement the [asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701.aspx).  To prevent threading issues, consider using the [SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163321.aspx).  [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997) does a great job at explaining these.

You can even consider using a BackgroundWorker.

Here is a nice Guide regarding Async and Sync calls:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/91528/How-to-Call-WCF-Services-Synchronously-and-Asynchr

Comment: In this article is well discussed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327096/is-backgroundworker-the-only-way-to-keep-a-wcf-wpf-application-responsive in your case (Simple case) the quicker solution could be the Background Worker.